# Faster Continuous Integration process with BDD

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, jenkins, cucumber, bdd

We run BDD tests (Cucumber/Selenium) with Jenkins in a Continuous Integration process. The number of tests is increasing day by day and the time to run these tests is getting higher, making the whole CI process not really responsive (if you commit in the afternoon you would risk to see your building results the day after).  Is there a way/pattern to keep the CI process quick in spite of increasing number of tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could choose one of the following schemes:

1. Seperate projects for unit tests and integration tests. The unit tests will return their results faster and the integration project will run once or just a couple of times per day and not after each commit. The drawback is obvious, if the integration tests suite break there is no correlation with the breaking change.
2. Google approach - sort your tests according to their size: small, medium, large and enormous. Use separate projects for each kind of test and according to the total time it takes to run the specific test suite. You can read more in [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321803027) book. Also, read [this](http://googletesting.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/how-google-tests-software.html#!/2011/01/how-google-tests-software.html) blog to get more wise ideas.
3. Try to profile your current test suite to eliminate bottlenecks. This might bring it back to give feedback in a timely fasion.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

@Ikaso gave some great answers there.  One more option would be to set up some [build slaves](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) (if you haven't already) and split the integration tests into multiple jobs that can be run in parallel on the slaves.